# MySQL: select surname ONLY from the column with name and surname

Tags: mysql, sql, string, select

I have a column which contains client's name and surname in `CUSTOMER` table.

```
11 | John Doe
12 | Kate Sanchez 
13 | Amy Lee
```

The purpose is to select only id-s and names to be displayed in the column, like:

```
11 | Doe
12 | Sanchez 
13 | Lee
```

The length of names varies, so I can't use SUBSTRING.

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(column, ' ', -1)`

Comment: What about a name like 'Edward de Souza'?

Comment: Fortunately, in this task I have no such names, and can not to count 'em

Comment: Then you have your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Do you want `substring_index()`?

```
select id, substring_index(name, ' ', -1) last_name
from customer
```

This selects the part of the string that follows the last space.